# convert json string into knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am trying to convert a JSON string into a knockout.js observable array.

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var model =  function(dat){
        this.tabledata = ko.observableArray(dat);
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:1141/rest_service/show_data',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(msg){
            // var dat = JSON.parse(msg);

            alert(msg);
            ko.applyBindings(new model(msg));
        },
        error: function(msg){
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        },
    });
});
```

and here is my html:

```
<table id = "example" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Status</th>
            <th>Date of birth</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: tabledata'>
       <tr>
           <td data-bind='text: $parent.empId'/></td> 
            <td data-bind='text: $parent.empStatus'/></td>
            <td data-bind='text:$parent.dob'/></td>
            <td data-bind='text: $parent.empName'/></td>
            <td data-bind='text: $parent.age'/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So here, after an ajax call, I am getting a JSON string as a response from the server and I want to bind this data to html table.

I tried using `ko.mapping.fromJs()` to convert the incoming JSON to an observable array but received the following error:

```
Error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.
```

The JSON response is as follows:

```
[
 {"empId":100,"empName":"TA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},   
 {"empId":101,"empName":"TA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},
 {"empId":102,"empName":"TATA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"1997-12-12","age":18},
 {"empId":103,"empName":"kljh","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},
 {"empId":111,"empName":"Aria","empStatus":"No","dob":"1995-10-17","age":20}
]
```

How can I change my code so that the JSON string is converted properly into a Knockout.js observable array?

Comment: simple do `this.tabledata([ko.mapping.fromJs(msg)()])` . let me know

Comment: if you can share your `json` structure it will be useful further down .

Comment: hey @super cool thanx for reply :) I tried ur given solution but still its nt working for me. I hav shared json structure in my above post. I tried ur solution n tried to see what data get stored in tabledata using alert. It shows function function d(){if(0<arguments.length)return d.Wa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Ob(d);return c}..

Comment: Try using $.getJSON instead. Take a look at the following [tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving)

Comment: check here in fiddle sample http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/25299/ & check console window for output .As far your structure goes use `$data` instead of `$parent` in view .

Comment: @super cool .. thanx for reply.. I tried ur above solution . When I define static JSON string as u hav given in fiddle sample, it works fine n show proper binded html table data but when i bind my ajax response with table and use alert to see my tabledata value it shows ajax response is properly initialize to it but still it doesn't get properly bind to html table... :(

Comment: @Waynw Ellery : I tried $.getJSON too n referred same tutorial but m getting same error

Comment: @PriyankaMokashi check console window and let me the error . cheers . if something works static it must & will work dynamic .

Comment: @ super cool  thanx :) Nw I m getting output with dynamic binding too.. your code helped me alot :) Actually i forgot to convert my JSON string into JSON object before binding my table data. Nw its giving me proper output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like below

```
var json = [{"empId":100,"empName":"TA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},{"empId":101,"empName":"TA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},{"empId":102,"empName":"TATA","empStatus":"yes","dob":"1997-12-12","age":18},{"empId":103,"empName":"kljh","empStatus":"yes","dob":"2000-12-12","age":15},{"empId":111,"empName":"Aria","empStatus":"No","dob":"1995-10-17","age":20}]

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.list = ko.observable(ko.mapping.fromJS(json)());
        console.log(this.list());
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

In view use `$data` instead of `$parent` as per your view structure .

working sample fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/28079/)**

Comment: i try it but it's not working. it will display blank row.if any other method. let me know

Comment: @PHPDeveloper updated the fiddle in my answer . it looks fine . cheers